# how to call ascx page from a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have an ascx page and it contain certain methods...
on click i want to make a jquery ajax call to the controller and call the ascx page methods..
how can i do this?????????

Comment: I think you're missing a verb in your title. How to WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to create a .aspx page that just contains your control and call that - there is no way to call the .ascx directly.

You are using web forms not MVC?

Comment: You're right, I misread the question obviously there's no available url to an ascx.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery ajax() is your friend here..... [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

RFM

Comment: While true that jQuery ajax is what is needed, this is not a suitable answer, as it misses over the specific detail of the question.

RFQ.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this!

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "script address here",
     type: 'GET',
     data: data,
     success: function(msg) {

    }
 });
```